# How to Center a Splash Screen

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I'm converting an app from the iPhone to the iPad. The splash screen picture is the right size but when I enter the app after about half a second the picture goes from being perfectly sized to having the bottom and right areas out of screen and white areas above and to the left of the picture. How do I get it to stay in the screen the way it's loaded and not moved out of the screen?

Comment: you don't have to do anything like that.. check you image size

Answer (score 0):

The way it's loaded is probably from a default picture (Default.png). This picture is taken from the iPhone version and is being scaled. You can't make it so that this picture stays.

Check the `autoresizingMask` and `frame` properties of your view/picture and maybe also the `bounds` property.

Comment: the x and y are both 0, the w and h are 768 and 1004 respectively and in all teh red bars are highlighted in the autosizing and it still happens

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the status bar:

Maybe you did hide it in the iPhone version, and now you should hide it again for the iPad. Check the info.plist of your app

Comment: i have a copy version i saved seperate before i started on the ipad one and that seems to be working grand